# Can I install Paint.Net on linux using mono?

Tags: mono

I tried downloading and running the Paint.NET installer under mono and got:

> Cannot open assembly 'Paint.NET.3.5.8.Install.exe':
>   File does not contain a valid CIL image.

Can this be installed using mono?

If it matters, I'm running Ubuntu.

Comment: This might be a better fit for SuperUser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, Paint.NET will not run on Mono.

There was some (currently abandoned) [effort](http://code.google.com/p/paint-mono/) to port it to non-Windows systems.

Also, it has inspired [Pinta](http://pinta-project.com/), a project which is supposed to be drop-in replacement for Paint.NET on non-Windows systems.

Comment: Please note that Pinta does not support the Paint.NET internal *.pdn file format.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't install windows apps with mono. But you can install most windows apps with wine.

If you have the source code you can try to use mono to recompile it and create a linux binary.

Comment: Currently (see date of the comment) it is impossible to install paint.net on wine, because the required .NET 4.7.1 won't install on wine.